# Convert swf file to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: flash, command-line, ffmpeg, command-line-arguments, mp4

I need to convert swf files to mp4 files using ffmpeg commands (command line). There is text in swf files which must be converted too. 
But when I convert files using the following ffmpeg command text in swf file is not converted to mp4 / no text is visible in mp4 file:

```
ffmpeg -i file.swf video.mp4
```

Is there any other command to convert text?

Comment: After hours of searching, I found this app that does convert .swf to mp4 and html5 with sound and everything in sync and many other formats also in batch: `iDealshare_VideoGo_6.0.6.5638`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ffmeg` doesn't support [shapes and sprites](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1956) in `swf`. It can only convert video (Sorenson Spark, VP6), audio (pcm, adpcm, mp3) and images (jpeg) contained in a `swf` file. You'll have to look for another tool.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you know of any other tool which does the conversion?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any 3rd party tool. Adobe Flash had the option to export an animation as a video if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. My walk around was to use the raw-output of *gnash*.

The following bash script summarizes the single steps.

```
#!/bin/bash

SWFFILE=$1
MP4FILE=${SWFFILE%.*}.mp4
TMPFILE=/tmp/$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1).bin
TMPMP4=/tmp/$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1).mp4

# create raw-dump
GNASHCMD="dump-gnash -1 -r 1 -D $TMPFILE $SWFFILE"
OUTPUT="$(exec $GNASHCMD)"

# extract parameters
WIDTH="$(echo $OUTPUT | grep -o 'WIDTH=[^, }]*' | sed 's/^.*=//')"
HEIGHT="$(echo $OUTPUT | grep -o 'HEIGHT=[^, }]*' | sed 's/^.*=//')"
FPS="$(echo $OUTPUT | grep -o 'FPS_ACTUAL=[^, }]*' | sed 's/^.*=//')"

# create raw, uncompressed mp4 file
mplayer $TMPFILE -vo yuv4mpeg:file=$TMPMP4 -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo fps=$FPS:w=$WIDTH:h=$HEIGHT:format=bgra

# create compressed mp4 (ffmpeg should work as well)
avconv -i $TMPMP4 $MP4FILE

# clean up
rm -rf $TMPFILE
rm -rf $TMPMP4
```

Comment: how to include sound into result MP4 in Your example?